# After custom modal dismissal transition the first view controller's lifecycle methods don't get called

Tags: ios, swift, uicollectionview, uistoryboardsegue

I have two view controllers: `viewController1` and `viewController2`. `viewController1` contains a collection view with several cells.

They are connected by a modal segue. For navigation between them I create two animators for showing `viewController2` (`showAnimator`) and for dismissing it (`dismissAnimator`).

In `dismissAnimator` I animate both the `fromView` (`viewController2`'s view) and `toView` (`viewController1`'s view). Here are the two methods for doing that:

```
 private func animateFromViewDisappearance(fromView: UIView?, withDuration duration: TimeInterval, usingTransitionContext transitionContext: UIViewControllerContextTransitioning?) {
    guard let containerView = transitionContext?.containerView, let fromView = fromView else {return}

    UIView.animate(withDuration: duration, delay: 0.0, usingSpringWithDamping: 1.0, initialSpringVelocity: 1.0, options: .curveEaseInOut, animations: {
        fromView.transform = CGAffineTransform(scaleX: 1.5, y: 1.5)
        fromView.alpha = 0.0
    }, completion: {_ in

    })
}

 private func animateToViewAppearance(toView: UIView?, withDuration duration: TimeInterval, usingTransistionContext transitionContext: UIViewControllerContextTransitioning?) {
    guard let containerView = transitionContext?.containerView, let toView = toView else {
        return}


    toView.frame = containerView.frame
    toView.transform = CGAffineTransform(scaleX: 0.01, y: 0.01)
    toView.alpha = 0.0
    containerView.addSubview(toView)

    UIView.animate(withDuration: duration, delay: 0.3, usingSpringWithDamping: 1.0, initialSpringVelocity: 1.0, options: .curveEaseInOut, animations: {
        toView.transform = CGAffineTransform(scaleX: 1.0, y: 1.0)
        toView.alpha = 1.0
    }) { (success) in
        if success {
            transitionContext?.completeTransition(true)
        }
    }
}
```

These methods are called from `animateTransition(using:)`.

The problem is that after the animation ends, in `viewController1` cells of the collection view don't appear. I just get the view of the view controller and the collection view itself. I've checked and noticed that lifecycle methods of the view controller don't get called either, however, `viewDidLayoutSubviews` does get called. Collection view data source methods don't get called, too, so that's why the cells don't appear.

I know I'm missing something quite simple but can't figure out what. I've also checked a few answers here, but none of them helped me.

If you know how to resolve this problem, I would appreciate your help.

Comment: Why don't you call `complete` in the first function?

Comment: @Alper, I need to call it after the transition is done, however, that method only animates `viewController2` off the screen, but the transition is still happening (I need to animate the `viewController1`). If I call it there the app crashes because it expects that after the call, all transition animations are done.

Comment: These are called at the same time?

Comment: @Alper, one after another in `animateTransition(using:)` method.

Comment: Are you sure that `complete` is called?

Comment: @Alper, yes. The breakpoint gets hit.

Comment: And if you don't animate, it does work?

Comment: @Alper, if I go back to `viewController1` without custom animation?

Comment: That should work otherwise we're debugging the wrong thing.

Comment: @Alper, only if I also disable an animation for showing `viewController2`

Comment: @Alper, If I don't do that, I get a blank screen. That's because I'm presenting the second view controller modally with default presentation style.

Comment: You can't just `dismiss` the second view controller and end up at the same first one with the `UICollectionView`?

Comment: @Alper, I can do that if I use the default transition, but when I disable only my custom dismiss one, while the custom transition for showing `viewController2` is still enabled, then, yes  I can't see the first view controller after returning back

Answer (score 0, accepted):

After spending some time I finally found a solution. As it is said in Apple's docs, we can't directly call view controller's lifecycle methods (well, we can but it isn't recommended). To call `viewController1` lifecycle methods I call `beginAppearanceTransition(_:animated:)` method from animator:

```
 toViewController?.beginAppearanceTransition(true, animated: true)
```

Now, this indeed calls the view controller's lifecycle methods, but the view layout becomes a completely mess (I think, that's because when initially transitioning from the `viewController1` I change not only its location but also its scale).

So, finally I found a solution to that problem, too. To solve it, when transitioning from `viewController1`, I animate not the view controller itself (its location and scale), but I use its snapshot (the following code is in the animator for transitioning from `viewController1` to `viewController2`):

```
 let snapshot = UIApplication.shared.keyWindow?.snapshotView(afterScreenUpdates: false)
```

After having the snapshot, as soon as the transition starts I insert the snapshot into the `containerView` on top of a `viewController1`, and remove `viewController1` from the superview. Now, I animate the snapshot, which mimics the `viewController1`.

This works fine for me. Maybe it will work for someone else.